# Notation: covariance on scalars?

Tags: covariance, notation

I've recently seen the degrees-of-freedom for K-nearest neighbors regression specified like so:

$\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^NCov(y_i,\hat{y}_i)$

But what does $Cov(y_i,\hat{y}_i)$ mean?  Previously I've understood the notation $Cov(X,Y)$ to mean the covariance of the vectors $X$ and $Y$, resulting in a scalar.  Here, the inputs $y_i$ and $\hat{y}_i$ are themselves scalars.  I am confused.

Comment: Can you provide some context regarding where you have recently seen this? Eg can you paste in a quote &/or provide a cite?

Comment: For a citable context, see page 77, equation 3.60, of Elements of Statistical Learning: http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/printings/ESLII_print10.pdf

Comment: I imagine gung was asking for a cite for in the expression $\text{Cov}(X,Y)$ only referring to vectors. Generally in an expression like $\text{Cov}(X,Y)$, $X$ and $Y$ represent random variables (which could indeed be scalar).

Comment: e.g. see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Definition)

Comment: and section 2] 1) for example : https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~epxing/Class/10708-15/notes/10708_scribe_lecture20.pdf, hard to understand....
the question is still open for me

Answer (score 4):

This is the [standard definition of the covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Definition):
$$
\newcommand{\Cov}{\mathrm{Cov}}
\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}}
\Cov(X, Y) = \E\left[ \left( X - \E[X] \right) \left( Y - \E[Y] \right) \right]
,$$
where here $X$ and $Y$ are real-valued random variables.

With an $n$-dimensional random vector $X$, the typical notation is
$$
\Cov(X) = \left[ \Cov(X_i, X_j) \right]_{ij}
,$$
i.e. you get an $n \times n$ matrix where the $(i, j)$th entry is the covariance between $X_i$ and $X_j$.

I'm not familiar with a notation $\Cov(X, Y)$, where $X$ and $Y$ are random vectors and the covariance is a scalar.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that $y_i$ and $ \hat{y}_i$ are vectors with respective means $ \bar{y}_i $ and $\hat{\bar{y}}_i$ respectively.

Maybe they should have specified $ 1/\sigma^2 $ $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n$ ($y_i$ - $ \bar{y}_i $)($ \hat{y}_i$ - $\hat{\bar{y}}_i$).

I will look into K-nearest neighbors regression and get back as I don't know the underlying theory.

Comment: I haven't looked up the context, but $y_i$ is almost certainly the scalar dependent variable and $\hat y_i$ the output of the regression.

Comment: Oops sorry, i mentioned vectors and showed it in scalar notation. Yes, $y_i$ should be the i$^th$ element of vector Y, looks like.

Answer (score 0):

It follows from the definition of the [*effective degrees of freedom*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom_(statistics)#In_non-standard_regression) given by the trace of the hat matrix, $\nu=\mathrm{tr}(H)$; the diagonal of $H$ equals the ratio of the covariance between $\hat{y}$ and $y$ and the variance of $y$ ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_matrix#Definition)).